# How to pass an integer as command line argument in turbo c++

Tags: c++, command-line, turbo-c++

I am unable to pass integer value through the command line in turbo c++.
Please help me.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass arguments to executable only as strings. You could use [`std::atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) to convert string to integer.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  if ( argc > 1 ) {
    int i = atoi( argv[1] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to pass it through as a string, and then parse it with something like [`atoi`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/atoi/) or [`strtol`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/).

Command line arguments are always strings (or `char*`s if you want to be picky :)

Comment: not what @Kumar wanted, but worth mentioning for future reference: `atof` (convert string to float), `strtoul` (convert string to unsigned long),  `atol` (convert string to long int), and `strtod` (convert string to double)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot pass integers from the command line, only strings. Pass in your number, and use `::atoi` (or any other conversion function) to convert it to an integer

Answer (score 1):

I really wonder why you are still sticking to the ancient compiler! The sooner you switch to modern compilers the better it is!
Anyways the code for doing that is below:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream.h>
int main(int lenArgs, char *args[]){
    int num = 0;
    if (lenArgs > 1){
        num = atoi(args[1]);
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Please give an argument to the program!";
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<num<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing it in just for this one time, and you don't need to maintain the parameters you can give your main function, you can convert the `char*` parameters the C++ runtime provides your program with by using `int i = atoi( argv[1] )`.

If you're going to have more parameters, you probably want some way to name them, too.  Then it's worth taking a look at the [`getopt`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html) function.  This one allows for more flexible command line parameters.

There even are command-line parsing frameworks out there that allow for type-checking and the lot.